# ReacNativa Text Input component activation space problem

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, input

Peace...

I'm trying to make a text input component which receives input from user like below:
[All inputs from user...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1v1r.png)

```
//AppTextInput (main supplier)    
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

import defaultStyles from '../config/styles';

export default function AppTextInput({ icon, ...otherProps }) {

    // const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
    // const [isNew, setIsNew] = useState(false);

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>

            {icon && <MaterialCommunityIcons name={icon} size={20}
                color={defaultStyles.colors.medium} style={styles.icon}
            />}

            <TextInput style={defaultStyles.text} {...otherProps}
                placeholderTextColor={defaultStyles.colors.medium}
            />

        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: defaultStyles.colors.light,
        borderRadius: 25,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        width: '100%',
        padding: 15,
        marginVertical: 10,
    },
    icon: {
        marginRight: 10,
        alignSelf: 'center',
    }
});



//config/styles (styling code)

import { Platform } from 'react-native';

import colors from './colors';

export default {
    colors,
    text: {
        color: colors.dark,
        fontSize: 18,
        fontFamily: Platform.OS === "android" ? "Roboto" : "Avenir",
    },
}




//AppFormField (for forms)
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { useFormikContext } from 'formik';

import AppTextInput from '../AppTextInput';
import ErrorMessage from './ErrorMessage';

export default function AppFormField({ name, ...otherProps }) {

    const { errors, handleChange, setFieldTouched, touched } = useFormikContext();

    return (
        <>
            <AppTextInput
                onBlur={() => setFieldTouched(name)}
                onChangeText={handleChange(name)}
                {...otherProps}
            />
            <ErrorMessage error={errors[name]} visible={touched[name]} />
        </>
    );
}




//ListingEditScreen (this the main window to user)

export default function ListingEditScreen() {
  return (
    <Screen style={styles.container}>
      <Form
        initialValues={{
          title: "",
          price: "",
          description: "",
          category: null,
        }}
        onSubmit={(values) => console.log(values)}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
      >
        <AppFormField maxLength={255} name="title" placeholder="Title" />
        <AppFormField
          keyboardType="numeric"
          maxLength={8}
          name="price"
          placeholder="Price"
          width={120}
        />
        <Picker
          items={categories}
          name="category"
          numberOfColumns={3}
          PickerItemComponent={CategoryPickerItem}
          placeholder="Category"
          width="50%"
        />
        <AppFormField
          maxLength={255}
          multiline
          name="description"
          numberOfLines={3}
          placeholder="Description"
        />
        <SubmitButton title="Post" />
      </Form>
    </Screen>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    padding: 10,
  },
});
```

but my problem is that the input field only gets acitvated when I touch the placeholder text and not any other part of the text input field!

[My main problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vePY3.png)

So how can I solve this problem so that I can touch any part of the input field and it gets activated!

Thank-you!

Comment: Please add your code to the question details

Comment: Please add the component code, along with the styling.

Comment: Please see the code now!